# How to chain try() and scoped to_s() in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In a Rails view, one can use `try` to output only if there is a value in the database, e.g

```
@model.try(:date)
```

And one can chain trys if, for example, the output is needed as a string

```
@model.try(:date).try(:to_s)
```

But what if I need to call a scoped format? I've tried

```
@model.try(:date).try(:to_s(:long))
@model.try(:date).try(:to_s).try(:long)
```

What is the correct syntax for this? And what is a good reference for more explanation?

Thanks

Answer (score 17, accepted):

From the [fine manual](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Object.html#method-i-try):

> **try(*a, &b)**
>   [...]
>   `try` also accepts arguments and/or a block, for the method it is trying
>
> ```
> Person.try(:find, 1)
> ```

So I think you want:

```
@model.try(:date).try(:to_s, :long)
```

---

This one won't work:

```
@model.try(:date).try(:to_s(:long))
```

because you're trying to access the `:to_s` symbol as a method (`:to_s(:long)`). This one won't work:

```
@model.try(:date).try(:to_s).try(:long)
```

because you're trying to call the `long` method on what `to_s` returns and you probably don't have a `String#long` method defined.

Answer (score 6):

[mu is too short's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10360517/292586) shows the correct usage for the `try` method with parameters:

```
@model.try(:date).try(:to_s, :long)
```

However, if you are using Ruby 2.3 or later, you should stop using `try` and give the safe navigation operator a try (no pun intended):

```
@model&.date&.to_s(:long)
```

**The following answer is here for historical purposes – adding a `rescue nil` to the end of statements is considered bad practice, since it suppresses all exceptions:**

> For long chains that can fail, I'd rather use:
>
> ```
> @model.date.to_s(:long) rescue nil
> ```
>
> Instead of filling up my view with `try(...)` calls.
>
> Also, try to use `I18n.localize` for date formatting, like this:
>
> ```
> l @model.date, format: :long rescue nil
> ```
>
> See:
>   http://rails-bestpractices.com/posts/42-use-i18n-localize-for-date-time-formating

Comment: Thanks Fabio, this is really useful info. I've learned something new.

Comment: avoid rescue nil unless you're 120% sure you're not missing out on any other errors and you also don't care about performance (raise:ing exceptions is slow)

Comment: You are right, @SimonB. Unfortunately, I didn't knew about it when I first posted the answer, in 2012. I've edited it, thanks for noticing.

Answer (score 1):

In case you often use try chains without blocks, an option is to extend the Object class:

```
class Object
  def try_chain(*args) 
    args.inject(self) do |result, method| 
      result.try(method)
    end
  end
end
```

And then simply use `@model.try_chain(:date, :to_s)`